# Adium connect to local ejabberd server on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am new in ejabberd and XMPP in general. I have setup ejabberd on a mac running Mountain Lion.
Unfortunately when I try to connect to the local ejabberd server using Adium client, it gives the error "**Server closed the connection**".

EDIT: I installed ejabberd from the [installer for OS X provided in process one website](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/).

Below is the ejabberd log:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2013-09-19 01:47:35 ===
** State machine <0.2118.0> terminating 
** Last event in was {xmlstreamelement,
                         {xmlelement,"starttls",
                             [{"xmlns","urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"}],
                             []}}
** When State == wait_for_feature_request
**      Data  == {state,{socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.15371>,<0.2117.0>},
                        ejabberd_socket,#Ref<0.0.0.48234>,false,"533022348",
                        {sasl_state,"jabber","localhost",[],
                                    #Fun<ejabberd_c2s.1.52538782>,
                                    #Fun<ejabberd_c2s.2.77839348>,
                                    #Fun<ejabberd_c2s.3.97921512>,undefined,
                                    undefined},
                        c2s,c2s_shaper,false,true,false,false,
                        [verify_none,
                         {certfile,"/Applications/ejabberd-2.1.13/conf/server.pem"}],
                        false,undefined,[],"localhost",[],undefined,
                        {pres_t,0},
                        {pres_f,0},
                        {pres_a,0},
                        {pres_i,0},
                        undefined,undefined,undefined,false,
                        {userlist,none,[],false},
                        unknown,unknown,
                        {{127,0,0,1},59697},
                        [],[]}
** Reason for termination = 
** {{case_clause,{error,{open_error,-11}}},
    [{tls,tcp_to_tls,2},
     {ejabberd_socket,starttls,3},
     {ejabberd_c2s,wait_for_feature_request,2},
     {p1_fsm,handle_msg,10},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 2013-09-19 01:47:40 ===
** State machine <0.2120.0> terminating 
** Last event in was {xmlstreamelement,
                         {xmlelement,"starttls",
                             [{"xmlns","urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"}],
                             []}}
** When State == wait_for_feature_request
**      Data  == {state,{socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.15373>,<0.2119.0>},
                        ejabberd_socket,#Ref<0.0.0.48243>,false,"89255482",
                        {sasl_state,"jabber","localhost",[],
                                    #Fun<ejabberd_c2s.1.52538782>,
                                    #Fun<ejabberd_c2s.2.77839348>,
                                    #Fun<ejabberd_c2s.3.97921512>,undefined,
                                    undefined},
                        c2s,c2s_shaper,false,true,false,false,
                        [verify_none,
                         {certfile,"/Applications/ejabberd-2.1.13/conf/server.pem"}],
                        false,undefined,[],"localhost",[],undefined,
                        {pres_t,0},
                        {pres_f,0},
                        {pres_a,0},
                        {pres_i,0},
                        undefined,undefined,undefined,false,
                        {userlist,none,[],false},
                        unknown,unknown,
                        {{127,0,0,1},59698},
                        [],[]}
** Reason for termination = 
** {{case_clause,{error,{open_error,-11}}},
    [{tls,tcp_to_tls,2},
     {ejabberd_socket,starttls,3},
     {ejabberd_c2s,wait_for_feature_request,2},
     {p1_fsm,handle_msg,10},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
```

Can you help me to understand what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many unsuccessful trials I suspected that something might be missing with the setup of ejabberd based on the installer provided by process one. So, I uninstalled ejabberd and reinstalled it again from mac ports.

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install ejabberd
```

After the above installation I registered an admin with id of **lefam@localhost**. Finally, I could successfully connect to the server using Adium.

Comment: I had been facing the same problem using 2.1.8 and 2.1.13 versions. It looks like quadratic behavior in reading certificate data OR Dix http_bind webserver is problematic in those versions for mac.
Though 2.1.11 version worked fine for me.